# Entity Framework Code first add trim function commonly in where clause using Interceptor

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

I am using EF6 with Multiple Databases(SQL SERVER,ORACLE) We are Migrating from SQL Server to Oracle. everything works in SQL server. In Oracle we are facing issue of trim char column. i have used this link  [trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins](https://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/)  to solve issue.
this Interceptor adding trim function in select like below

```
SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."CAT")) AS "CAT",
    LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."CODE1")) AS "CODE1",
```

but i want to add LTRIM(RTRIM function in where clause like this

```
WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."CODE1")) =  :p__linq__2 ))
```

i googled it but did not get any proper solution.Is there any way to this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: RTRIM and LTRIM those are not working in oracle, you can use TRIM(Column)

Comment: @Thangadurai.B i want to add trim function commonly in where clause using Interceptor